# How do I get the calling instance of an object from inside a method in its parent class?

Tags: php

I have model class that looks like this

```
class Model {
  public static function build(params=array()) {
    $obj = WHAT DO I PUT HERE?

    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
      $obj->{$key} = $value;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

My Modal class gets extended

```
class Post extends Model {
  public $id;
  public $title;
}
```

I want to be able to do this

```
$post = new Post;
$post->build(SOME_PARAMS);

print $post->title;
```

and have it print the title.

How would I go about this?

I have tried using `$this` in the Model class, but I get an error about using `$this` out of context.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the method static if it needs to access the object it's called through. In an ordinary method you can access the object with `$this`.

```
class Model {
  public function build(params=array()) {

    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
      $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```